# Format cell mm:ss.00

Tags: excel, time, format, excel-2007, cell

I need to format a cell with minutes:seconds:hundreds.

I've look at Excel's own help which links to http://excelribbon.tips.net/T007557_Formatting_for_Hundredths_of_Seconds.html and they say to enter into a Custom > type box: "[h]:mm:ss.00".

[image]

That's a no-go with

[image]

I've tried

- hh:mm:ss.00
- [t]:mm:ss.00
- [h]:mm:ss.00
- mm:ss.00
- mm:ss:00
- mm.ss.00

And maybe some more in all this confusion. Any tips?

Comment: If you donwvote, please explain why.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting and by pure luck i tried

```
mm:ss.[t]
```

which seems to do the trick.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you use comma as the decimal separator so perhaps it should be [h]:mm:ss,000

Comment: I used a punctuation. One can see a comma below in the examples (in the image) and it seems clear I've used punctuation.